# How to use GeometryReader position Rectangle relative to top left corner of another Rectangle In SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have three rectangles stacked on a ZStack, they all have their own coordinateSpace. I want to place the PinkRectangle in the upper left corner of the YellowRectangle, the corresponding code is: .position(x: proxy.frame(in: .named(" YellowRectangle")).minX, y: proxy.frame(in: .named("YellowRectangle")).minY). The rendering result shows that the PinkRectangle has position to the upper left corner of the screen. What is the cause of the error here?

[image]

Full example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let uiScreenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    private let uiScreenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.cyan)
                    .frame(width: uiScreenWidth * 0.9, height: uiScreenHeight * 0.9)
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "CyanRectangle")
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                    .frame(width: uiScreenWidth * 0.6, height: uiScreenHeight * 0.6)
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "YellowRectangle")
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.pink)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .position(x: proxy.frame(in: .named("YellowRectangle")).minX,
                              y: proxy.frame(in: .named("YellowRectangle")).minY)
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "PinkRectangle")
            }
            .background(.gray)
        }
        .border(.black, width: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `.overlay(alignment: .topLeading)` instead of manually positioning it?

Comment: See also [How does .position modifier change layout of parent Stack in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76783228/20386264)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three reasons why it is not working as you expected:

1. You seem to be expecting that `GeometryProxy.frame` gives you the frame of the container with the coordinate space. It is actually giving you the frame of the `GeometryReader`, which has the black border. [Additional note: iOS 17 adds the method `bounds(of:)` to `GeometryProxy`, which does give you the bound's rectangle of a coordinate space.]
2. I would assume that coordinate spaces do not work across stacks. So the item being positioned has to be inside the coordinate space you're trying to reference.
3. The `GeometryReader` also needs to be inside the coordinate space you're trying to reference.

Of course, the item being positioned also needs to be inside the `GeometryReader`, otherwise the `GeometryProxy` will not be in scope.

What this all means, is that using `.position` in connection with a `GeometryProxy.frame` is only going to be useful when the `GeometryReader` is not occupying the full container space.

Looking at your example:

- I would expect that minX and minY are delivered using the global coordinate space, because the yellow coordinate space is unknown to both the pink square and the `GeometryProxy`. This means, minX will be 0 and minY will be the height of the safe area inset at the top of the display.
- The pink square is half out of view horizontally, because `.position` positions a view by its center.
- It is just a coincidence that the pink square appears to align with the cyan rectangle on its top edge. If you run it on a device with different top insets (such as an iPhone 14 Pro) then it is clearly not aligned.
- The `ZStack` is extending to the full bounds of the `GeometryReader` as a consequence of having an item in the `ZStack` being positioned using `.position` (this being the pink square). See [How does .position modifier change layout of parent Stack in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76783228/20386264) for more elaboration.
- The reason why the background is gray all the way to the screen edges is because when a background is set using `.background()` (in other words, with round parenthesis taking a `ShapeStyle` as parameter, as opposed to curly braces which would be a `ViewBuilder` function), it ignores safe areas by default.

So here is an adapted example:

- The container for the yellow coordinate space is now a `VStack`
- The `GeometryReader` containing the pink square has been moved inside this `VStack`.
- A (new) orange Rectangle comes before the `GeometryReader` in the same `VStack`.
- The horizontal position of the pink square uses minX from the cyan coordinate space.
- The vertical position of the pink square uses minY from the yellow coordinate space.
- An adjustment of half the square's width and half the square's height is added to the x and y positions. This adjustment is in order to position the square by its top-left corner, instead of by its center.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.clear // expand ZStack to max bounds
        Group {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    .frame(height: 25)
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.pink)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

                        // .position positions the centre of view,
                        // adjustment of half width and half height
                        // needed to position top-left corner
                        .position(

                            // The frame being referenced here is the frame
                            // of the GeometryReader (with black border),
                            // not the frame of the container.
                            x: proxy.frame(in: .named("CyanRectangle")).minX + 50,
                            y: proxy.frame(in: .named("YellowRectangle")).minY + 50
                        )
                        .coordinateSpace(name: "PinkRectangle")
                }
                .border(.black, width: 1)
            }
            .frame(width: uiScreenWidth * 0.6, height: uiScreenHeight * 0.6)
            .coordinateSpace(name: "YellowRectangle")
            .background { Color.yellow }
        }
        .frame(width: uiScreenWidth * 0.9, height: uiScreenHeight * 0.9)
        .coordinateSpace(name: "CyanRectangle") // must follow after frame!
        .background { Color.cyan }
    }
    .background(.gray)
}
```

[image: CoordinateSpaces]

Observations:

- The pink square is shifted horizontally across by the same amount as the yellow rectangle is nested inside the cyan space, this being the offset of the `GeometryReader` inside the cyan coordinate space.
- The pink square is shifted vertically down by the height of the orange rectangle, this being the offset of the `GeometryReader` inside the yellow coordinate space.
- Something important that I discovered: the `coordinateSpace` needs to be defined *after* the frame is set on the container!

In conclusion, using coordinate spaces like this is quite a handy way of finding the dimensions of content *outside* the `GeometryReader`, when this other content is impacting the position of the `GeometryReader` inside a common container.