# How to precisely position shapes in a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swiftui

I have created a triangle shape like this:

```
struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to position it precisely on its "tip" (i.e., the `CGPoint.zero` in the Shape space) at some coordinates (represented by the red rectangle in the example below):

```
struct MapShapes: View {
    @State var angle: Double = 0.0
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                    Triangle()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .position(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))

                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                        .position(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))

            }
        }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

but would like to get this:

[image]

It looks like SwiftUI is using the shape's center as an anchor point. Is it possible to change that to the `.zero` point in the shape space?

Alternatively, I can recalculate the offset needed from the center, but it requires to take the shape size into account, which seems like an unnecessary chore.

Or should I follow a totally different approach than using a `ZStack` to position multiple shapes over the same view?

Comment: "but it requires to take the shape size into account" I'm assuming in your real code the shapes' sizes are not hardcoded as you have shown here? Otherwise calculating the offset is very easy.

Comment: @Sweeper indeed, sizes are dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ZStack` aligns the `.center` (by default) alignment guides of all its subviews, so they all coincide at a single point. Using the [`alignmentGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alignmentguide(_:computevalue:)-9mdoh) modifier, you can change where an alignment guide of a view is.

This is kind of like changing the "anchor" of a view. You can change the triangle's `.center` to its `.leading` and `.top`. instead.

```
ZStack(/*alignment: .center*/) {
    Triangle()
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        // do this separately for the horizontal and vertical axes
        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { $0[.leading] }
        .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[.top] }
    
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
}
```

This extends to multiple shapes - you should set each shape's alignment guide to an appropriate position relative to the shape, so that when these positions coincide, the shapes appear in the desired locations.

That said, I'd rather draw the shapes in an imperative style using [`Canvas`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/canvas). This way you can control the shapes' sizes and where everything is in an imperative way. e.g.

```
Canvas { gc, size in
    gc.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    let triangle = Triangle().path(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    gc.fill(triangle, with: .color(.black))
    let rectangle = Rectangle().path(in: .zero.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: -5))
    gc.fill(rectangle, with: .color(.red))
}
```

Side note: you do not work in "Shape space" in the `path(in:)` method. You should write `rect.origin` instead of `CGPoint.zero`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to replace `position` with `overlay` in this circumstance.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Triangle()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) { // <- Alignment here
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    .offset(x: -5, y: -5) // <- Customize offSet here
            }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The rectangle is just an aid for the example. Imagine that I have lots of triangles (and other shapes) to draw and position precisely on the background "canvas". Each shape is totally independent from the others.

Comment: @ZeJibe So how about using a `Canvas`? You even mentioned the word yourself.

Comment: Oh, It's totally different from the given example above. However, I still don't get your idea. If you want to fill up the ZStack with multiple independent shapes that overlay each other, there must be a rule for these shapes, right?.

Comment: @Sweeper looked into ```Canvas``` and it seems indeed the best option for what I am trying to achieve. If you want to give it as a proper answer with a simple example, I’ll happily accept it.

Comment: @ZeJibe I already gave an example at the end of my current answer.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a view in a `ZStack` is positioned using `.position`, the `ZStack` becomes greedy and uses all the space available (see [How does .position modifier change layout of parent Stack in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76783228/20386264)).

So, if the points are being positioned with `.position`, the triangles can simply be positioned using `.offset` or even `.padding`. The only other change needed is to apply `.topLeading` alignment to the `ZStack`:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    Triangle()
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .offset(x: 100, y: 100)

    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
        .position(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
}
```

If there were no points involved and no view is being positioned using `.position`, you just need to add `Color.clear` to the `ZStack` to have it use all of the available space:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    Color.clear

    // + triangles
}
```